# Show/Hide Content Editor Web Part Based on Sharepoint Custom Content Type

Tags: content-type, content-editor-web-part

I have created a room/resource reservation process using custom content event types. They are as follows:
*Reserve a Room
*Reserve an AV Resource
*Reserve the Conference Room

I have created a CEWP that uses jquery to show different diagrams for various setup options within the event type 'reserve the conference room.'

Currently the NewForm.aspx shows this CEWP for all content types listed above. I only want to show this CEWP for the content type event 'reserve the conference room.'

I believe I am missing something obvious about how to do this. But I'm stumped. I'm fairly new to Sharepoint, and all suggestions are welcome.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Typically in that scenario, I create custom New/Edit/DispForms for each content type if they need special formatting or display information.  The default NewForm is shared by all the content types and is differentiated by query string parameters on what to show when the item is selected from the New list drop down.

Comment: ,Thank you! Your suggestion worked perfectly, especially since there is the option to insert a custom list based on each content type.

Comment: Ah, but not accepted or even upvoted, and I am out of votes for today :-(.